# How to get all the parameters in following response in Android

Tags: android, json, notifications, response

**I want to get parameters from this response !!**

```
 Bundle[{custom={"custom data":{"notification_type":"offer","offer_id":4348}}, from=1013970362419, badge=1, message=birds view, android.support.content.wakelockid=4, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]
```

I want **offer_id** and **notification_id** , in above notification data

Comment: At first check Its proper json or not . I guess not

Answer (score 1):

As the response is received in `Bundle`, you cannot parse it directly. Instead you can get each parameter of bundle using **bundle.getString(key)** or **bundle.getInt(key)** whatever type of data is.

So in your response to get `offer_id`, first of all extract *custom* parameter as a string and convert it into `JSONObject`. Then you will be able to get `offer_id`.

E.g.

```
JSONObject keyData = new JSONObject(data.getString("custom"));
Gson gson = new Gson();
KeyValueModel keyValue= gson.fromJson(keyData.toString(), KeyValueModel .class);
String offerId = keyValue.getString("offer_id")
```